# how do i get beginning and ending dates of a variable week?

Tags: php, date

i got this from php.net.  it get's beginning and ending dates of current week.

```
<?php
function week($curtime) {
    $date_array = getdate (time());
    $numdays = $date_array["wday"];
    $startdate = date("Y-m-d", time() - ($numdays * 24*60*60));
    $enddate = date("Y-m-d", time() + ((7 - $numdays) * 24*60*60));
    $week['start'] = $startdate;
    $week['end'] = $enddate;
    return $week;
}
?>
```

how can the above be modified to look for start and end date of a variable week, more specifically a variable date.  so say a variable had a value of a date, and that date was last week or next week.  in the case of it being last week, the script should get the beginning and ending dates of last week.  in the case of it being next week, the script should get the beginning and ending dates of next weeek.

this next script is very similar to the above script but it leaves out weekend days.  maybe this one would be better to modify for a variable date.  doesn't matter which one of the 2 scripts you modify.  i just want to get beginning and end date of a variable date.

```
$today = time();
$wday = date('w', $today);
$datemon = date('m-d-Y', $today - ($wday - 1)*86400);
$datetue = date('m-d-Y', $today - ($wday - 2)*86400);
$datewed = date('m-d-Y', $today - ($wday - 3)*86400);
$datethu = date('m-d-Y', $today - ($wday - 4)*86400);
$datefri = date('m-d-Y', $today - ($wday - 5)*86400);
```

this doesn't seem to work:

```
$today = time($mydate);
```

Comment: Just envisaging 8-day weeks when daylight savings changes

Comment: Are the weeks based on the the variable date, or the actual start of a week that it happens to be in? for example variable date = `2014-09-17`, is that the beginning of the week, or would it be `2014-09-15`?

Comment: for the 17th, the start date would be the 15th and the end date the 19th.

Answer (score 1):

You can use DateTime and some math logic;

```
function getStartAndEndWeekDates($year, $week) {
    $date = new DateTime();
    $date->setTimezone( new DateTimeZone("Europe/London")  );
    $date->setISODate( $year, $week );
    //Echo'ing to test...
    echo "Start: ". $date->format('d-M-Y');
    echo PHP_EOL;
    echo "End: ".  $date->add(new DateInterval('P7D'))->format("d-M-Y");
}

getStartAndEndWeekDates(2014, 1);
```

#### [Live Preview](https://eval.in/188948)

Comment: nothing echoed and it made the rest of page not load.

Comment: What PHP version are you running?